# Как с содержания file_get_contents() сделать изображение

Tags: php

Как с содержания file_get_contents() сделать изображение, чтобы можно было сразу просмотреть его высоту и другие характеристики. Желательно без сохранения

```
       $content = file_get_contents($_POST['url']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так:

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_POST['url']));
if ($im !== false) {
$width = imagesx($im);
$height = imagesy($im);
}
```

[php.net imagecreatefromstring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php)

Answer (score 1):

Можно короче :)

```
file_put_contents('image_name.jpg', file_get_contents($_POST['url']));
```

Comment: А как характеристики просмотреть ?

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, в коде, который я привел - никак. В задаче этого не было я и подумал, что это не нужно :)

Максимум что можно сделать это узнать расширение файла (и то только по буквам после последней точки, что не гарантирует верное расширение)